# CSS Align text inside "shape"

Tags: css

I've been trying to change the position of the text inside the "Shape"
but it allways keep pushing to the left.

```css
bala {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p> <bala>21</bala> Done <MdError color='#fcb51b' /> In Progress:{inProgress} </p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `display: inline-flex;` to `display: inline-block;`, and then adding a `text-align: center;`:

```css
bala {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <bala>21</bala> Done
  <MdError color='#fcb51b' /> In Progress:{inProgress}
</p>
```

Comment: That was it! will have to read and understand that display property! Thanks!

Comment: @zemmsoares No problem, happy to help :) You can read about the `display` property here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1):

Adding `justify-content: center;` Solves the problem.

```css
bala {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    line-height: 22px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<p> <bala>21</bala> Done <MdError color='#fcb51b' /> In Progress:{inProgress} </p>
```